# Can't load dll when running app manually but work when running app through ide

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I came here because i'm in trouble with something strange.
I have a code that load a dll and retrieve a function from this dll.
I work on both windows and linux.
Everything work like a charm in linux, but when windows come, some problems follow!
I use Clion as IDE, when i compile my code and launch it from Clion, everything work, my dll is loaded, the function was fetched, all are ok.
But when i launch my application from it's directory, my app can't find the dll.
This is my current code for the loader (in fact this is normally something simple) :

```
void dllLoader(const char *libPath){
    void* handle = dlopen(libPath, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (!handle) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        }
    else{
        std::cout << "library loaded" << std::endl;
        dlclose(handle);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    dllLoader("RenderModule.dll");
    return 0;
}
```

And as i say, running this from my IDE was good (i get "library loaded" output) but when i run in directory and manually run the application,
i get  the "cannot open library : RenderModule.dll No such file or directory" output.

The target dll and the binary are stored in the same directory.
I use CMake 3.3 and Mingw to compile this code.
The stranger thing was when i check the running path of my application and i try to read the dll ,using std::ifstream and i can read the dll correctly! there probably something i don't get...

I don't know what to do to fix this problem, someone has an idea ?
If you need the dll code, i'll edit this post, but i don't think it was usefull because if this dll was loaded in linux/windows(under ide) i think the problem doesn't come from the dll, but i can be wrong.
Thank you in advance and, sorry for my english :/
Have a nice day !

Comment: *How* and *where* do you run the program "manually"? In which directory are you? In the same directory as the DLL? As the executable? As both? In a different directory?

Comment: I have no any experience with the library you are using to load the DLL. But I suggest you to look a bit more into `dlopen` flags. Maybe there is one equivalento to the `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` in Windows API.

Comment: The program binary was under the "C:\\Users\\Renaud\\.Clion\system\cmake\generated\Game-225940eb\Debug";
My dll are in the same directory.
I run my application "manually" with double click on the file, and if i use the function _getcwd to retrieve the current
working directory it tell me i'm in "C:\\Users\\Renaud\\.Clion\system\cmake\generated\Game-225940eb\Debug", that sound good to me.
(I get this response too when i execute my application through my IDE)
i'll gonna take my chance with LoadLibrary to see if it work.

Comment: Please `printf` the value of the `libPath` variable before the `dlopen` call :-)

Comment: How do you use dlopen on Windows? It is not a part of Win32 API.
According to the manuals dlopen does not search in current directory or in the directory of the main executable. That means you have to compare the environment variables set by CLion vs your environment without CLion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first, thank you for your response ! and sorry for the time i take (i don't have too much time to spent on this project)
I came here cause i have found the solution for my problem, and i think it may be helpful for other people stuck in "dll's hell" :p

I change my "dllLoader" function to use the Win32 API:

```
void dllLoader(const char *libPath){
    HMODULE handle = LoadLibrary(libPath);
    if (!handle) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open library: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "library loaded" << std::endl;
        FreeLibrary(handle);
    }
}
```

As i expected it fall in the first if branch and GetLastError return error code 127.
After some search, this error code was retrieved is some case, because the library dependencies can't be found.

In the past when, i try to execute my first application compiled with CLion outside the IDE
(manually, through windows explorer, it was a simple "hello world", so no reason to fail)
I got some error like "...unresolved symbols..", the compiler don't link all needed library at linking time, so your binary
always depends on external libs.
I need to put

```
set(GCC_CXX_FLAGS ${GCC_CXX_FLAGS} "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
```

Flag into my CMake config file to build my binary with all dependencies imported in it.

After some test, the problems was the same here, my DLL wasn't built with all dependencies and it depend and some other dll to run correctly.
the update of GCC_CXX_FLAGS resolve the problem for the application that load the dll but not for the dll itself.
I don't know if it exist a similar flag to compile library using cmake that let linker import all dependencies in my dll, but i know what i need to search.

@Alexey Omelchenko, you point something interesting in your comment, i have run an app inside and oustide my ide that just show the PATH env variable.
The only difference was inside the IDE the PATH as C:\MingW\bin folder, so it confirm what i was thinking, this is a dependencies problem.

Again sorry for my English and for my response time and thanks for your help :)
And have a nice day!